# Remove the dash present before the key value pair in a YAML file

Tags: java, yaml

It is known that the dash (`-`) in a YAML file before the key value pair is necessary to show that it is separate block(it is what I think). [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rBMB.png) shows the YAML I'm generating using **YamlBeans** jar.

```
field1:
-  childfield1:
      datafield1:
         param1:
            childparam: paramvalue
         param2:
            childparam2: paramvalue
         param3:
            childparam3: paramvalue
      datafield2: value2
```

For my codebase can't be changed, I have to somehow create the YAMLs as shown in [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B9J0.png) (a tab is appended in each line in yaml file) or remove the dash is removed. You can clearly observe that there are only two thin vertical lines in Figure 1 but three thin vertical lines in Figure 2 which shows the alignment of the blocks.

What I want to achieve is to remove that dash from the first block (at the child field) from the file. Using a YAML file reader and writer always introduces the dash.

Comment: not 100% clear.  is it correct to assume that you only want to produce something that looks _close_ to YAML (making the YAML writer do most of the hard work), but not 100% YAML?  Also, do you want Figure 2 (leading tab) or a result you do not show (like Figure 1, but without a leading - )?

Comment: @jameygraham I would like a Figure 1, but without a leading - . It looks something like [this](https://postimg.org/image/6onpen0xn/).

Comment: Both your figures show the same number of dashes (1) and only differ significantly in the left margin, making them the same for YAML semantics. You should edit your post and include the text for the second Figure (as I did for the first). The dash does not start a new block in YAML, there is no such concept. Instead in a block style sequence it introduces a new (sequence) item. Using a sequence with each item a single key/value pair (where the value can be complex) is normally done to preserve the order of the keys, which is otherwise not guaranteed (when you have multiple keys in a mapping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glancing quick at (but admittedly not being familiar with) YamlBeans, it doesn't look like it's easy to subclass the behavior of the Emitter.  One option though is to generate a temporary form in memory, then manipulate the results when writing out to a file.  For example

```
    // let YamlWriter write its contents to an in-memory buffer
    StringWriter temp = new StringWriter();
    YamlWriter yamlOut = new YamlWriter(temp);
    yamlOut.write(someObject);

    // then dump the in-memory buffer out to a file, manipulating lines that
    // start with a dash
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("someoutput.dat")));
    LineNumberReader in = new LineNumberReader(new StringReader(temp.toString()));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("-")) {
            line = line.substring(1);
        }
        out.println(line);
    }
```

my specifics may be off, but hopefully the approach of doing simple manipulations of a temporary copy is clear enough.

If I were personally doing this, I'd probably write a custom subclass of `java.io.Writer` and do the manipulation on the fly (but i haven't gone through YamlWriter/Emitter in enough detail to provide an example on how to do that)